# WebSphere JVM MXBeans

Tags: jvm, websphere, jmx

When using Oracle JVM, we can obtain a large amount of useful JVM data using the provided MXBeans like GarbageCollectorMXBean, MemoryMXBean etc. Are the same MXBeans available in case of a WebSphere JVM ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are available also on WebSphere, but it is somewhat tricky to access them remotely. I just completed a documentation that explains what you need to know to access these MXBeans:

http://code.google.com/p/xm4was/wiki/WebSphereJmx

The XM4WAS project also provides some tools to make that easier. The following document describes how to use them to set up VisualVM to monitor a WebSphere JVM:

http://code.google.com/p/xm4was/wiki/VisualVMHowTo

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it is java 1.5+.
WAS also has PMI you should look into.